# Why is the code in Timer Control executed only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written the following Code:

```
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int time = 60;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label2.Text = "" + time; 
    }
    protected void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time = time - 1;
        Label2.Text = "" + time;
    }
}
```

I am trying something similar to a Countdown Timer. The Output should be printed as '60' then '59' then '58' and so on. But the code in the timer gets executed only once i.e. the output is printed as '60' and then '59' and then the number stops decrementing.

Comment: You need to understand that the ASP.NET code is only executed *once* when the web server renders the page. Dynamic updates can not be performed from code-behind like this. This is *the* difference between web and desktop programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer is executed each second. But `int time` is not static, it will start is 60 each time the timer is executed. Try putting `DateTime.Now` into the label text and you will see that the Timer is not the issue.